# Can't set header after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I had tried set the header, but it does not work. I put return at the end of every lines already. Therefore it should not execute `res.json(data)` twice.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
//var users = require('./routes/users');
var api = require('./routes/api');
var users_page = require('./routes/users_page');
var quizzes = require('./routes/quizzes');
var subjects = require('./routes/subjects');
var questions = require('./routes/questions');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
//app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/users',users_page);
app.use('/quizzes', quizzes);
app.use('/subjects',subjects);
app.use('/questions',questions);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

---

users_page.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/mydb';

var userHandler = require('./userHandler_post.js'); 
router.post('/', userHandler.post);

var usr2 = require('./userHandler_getusrinfo.js');
router.get('/:username', usr2.getusrinfo);

var usr3 = require('./userHandler_upusr.js');
router.put('/:username', usr3.upusr);


var usr4 = require('./userHandler_del.js');
router.delete('/:username', usr4.del);


var usr5 = require('./userHandler_repasswd.js');
router.put('/reset_password/:username', usr5.repasswd);


var usr6 = require('./userHandler_getall.js');
router.get('/', usr6.get);

module.exports = router;
```

---

userHandler_getusrinfo.js :

```
var pg = require('pg');
var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL || 'postgres://admin:admin@localhost:5432/mydb';

exports.getusrinfo = function(req, res, callback) {

    var username = req.params.username;

  pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
    // Handle Errors
    if(err) {
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      res.json(err);
      return ;
    }

        var q2 = client.query("SELECT * FROM dugong.users WHERE UserName =$1 ;",[username]);

        q2.on('error', function(error) {
            var data = {success : false, 
                                    username : username,
                                    reason : {errmsg : error.detail,
                                                        errid : error.code} };  
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.json(data);
            return callback();
        });    

      q2.on('row', function(row, result) {
          result.addRow(row);
          return ;
      });

      q2.on('end', function(result) {

          if (result.rowCount == 0) {
                    var data = {success : false, 
                                            username : username, 
                                            reason : {errmsg : "Username not found", 
                                                                errid : 'q2'}};
                    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                    res.json(data);

                    return callback();
                }

                var sumdata = {success: true,
                                        username : result.rows[0].username,
                                        ... //omit to keep it short
                                        FaxNumber : result.rows[0].faxnum
                                        };
          res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
          res.json(sumdata);
          return callback();
      });
      done();
      return ;
  });
  pg.end();
};
```

However, I got the annoying message like this.
But program runs fine!

```
GET /users/Sari 500 45.026 ms - 89
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:700:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:154:12)
    at fn (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:934:10)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/jade/lib/index.js:374:12)
    at View.render (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:93:8)
    at EventEmitter.app.render (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:566:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.render (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:938:7)
    at /home/sarit/4alls/mariner/app.js:64:7
    at Layer.handle_error (/home/sarit/4alls/mariner/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:58:5)
```

Do I need to touch app.js:64:7 which is made by Express? If so, how can I do it in proper way?

Comment: Could you share your App.js file? Your error looks like it's coming from rendering a view. Maybe you're sending your JSON data and then trying to render and return a view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent?rq=1 could be useful

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT I just update my question.

Comment: @YannBertrand . I have read it. That is why I put res.setHeader() over res.json. I am still finding the root cause of it.

Comment: You're using `res.json` and calling `callback`, which is passing to the error handler.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put your q2 query code in else part.

Comment: @Kulwant . still same error and program run like no else{}

Comment: @Jan Any information do you need. I will provide you as fast as I can.

Comment: @Sarit I haven't met node.js closely yet so I am not capable of answering your question. I just like short answers to long questions.

Comment: @sarit i think here callback is acting as next so you next is being called.

Comment: @user111111111. I had accepted you answer, but my reputation is not over 15 yet. Very strange I had posted my comment already since Jul 7, but it gone.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be calling the `callback` (`next`) function if there isn't more work to be done or an error. You have a catchall in your `App.js` file (I'm assuming because you didn't post it), which is being hit because you called the `callback` (`next`) function. It's trying to render an error page, hence the call to Jade rendering.

Remove the `callback` calls.

Comment: Hi. I need callback since I am now creating an unit test. Therefore I create a checking function first to solve my problem. Thank you :)